# Uucp: copy...but not command execution allowed

Tags: mailx, uucp

I have setup a Unix machine with uucp (Unixware)
connected via direct serial to Slackware machine.
Using uucp.
The copy works

on Unixware

```
uucp -m /usr/bin/view Slackware1\!/var/spool/uucppublic


mailx
....
.....
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Status: R
Content-Length: 121

REQUEST: unixware2!/usr/bin/view --> Slackware1!/var/spool/uucppublic (myusername)
(SYSTEM: Slackware1)  copy succeeded
```

Now we try the mailx on remote and..

```
echo something|uux -z Slackware1\!/usr/bin/mailx myuser
```

On Slackware server the uucp log said..

```
ERROR: Not permitted to execute /usr/bin/mailx
```

Of course the mail don't arrive.

Those are the permission configuration

On Linux

/etc/uucp/sys

```
remote-send ~
remote-receive ~
local-send ~
local-receive ~
command-path /usr/bin
commands ls mailx
system   unixware2
time     any
port     serial1
speed    38400
chat     in:--in: nuucp word: ***
```

on unixware

/etc/uucp/Permissions

```
LOGNAME=nuucp \
MACHINE=OTHER \
READ=/var/spool/uucppublic \
WRITE=/var/spool/uucppublic \
SENDFILES=call REQUEST=yes \
COMMANDS=/usr/bin/rmail:/usr/bin/mailx \
PUBDIR=/var/spool/uucppublic \
MYNAME=unixware2 \
VALIDATE=Slackware1

LOGNAME=myusername \
MACHINE=OTHER \
READ=/var/spool/uucppublic \
WRITE=/var/spool/uucppublic \
SENDFILES=call REQUEST=yes \
COMMANDS=/usr/bin/rmail:/usr/bin/mailx \
PUBDIR=/var/spool/uucppublic \
MYNAME=unixware2 \
VALIDATE=Slackware1
```

any suggestion?Thanks

edit1:
Trying

```
uux -a nuucp..
```

make the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found

on /etc/uucp/sys

instead of

```
commands mailx
```

we use

```
commands /usr/bin/mailx
```

Works fine.

The command for sent email using mailx is this

```
uux - -z Slackware1\!/usr/bin/mailx -s subject myuser
```

or in one line

```
echo -e 'Hello, A message for you\nhow are you...blablabla' | uux - 'Slackware1!mailx myuser'
```

Comment: Congrats! Wait, I hear something... Ring, ring... Ring, ring... [auto-baud tones]  It's the 1980's. They want their modem back.

Comment: Sometimes I like to play with old technologies, remind me the 80's which are "80" or 100 better times than now, imho of course.